# Can a non-driver, non-worker create a Spark Session and read a CSV file into a Dataset?

Tags: java, apache-spark

Java 8 and Spark 2.4.5 (Scala 2.12) here. I'm also very new to Spark.

I'm trying to understand *when* code executes on the Spark driver node and *when* it gets submitted to workers/executors.

Specifically, when you create a `SparkContext` and `SparkSession` instance, do those instantiations *always* have to happen on the driver? Or is it possible to create a `SparkContext`/`SparkSession` instance on just a regular olde' JVM app (that is: a Java app that is neither a Spark driver not a worker/executor)?

Ditto for session reads. For instance, when I read a CSV file like so:

```
sparkSession.read()
  .format("csv")
  .load(providedFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

do those reads *always* have to execute on either a driver or worker, or can they just be executed on "normal Java app" that just happens to pull Spark Core in as a dependency?

---

**Edit**: it does seem that anything that creates the `SparkSession` *is* a "Spark Driver" by default, so then my only other question is: how do I tell which code executes on the driver and which code gets farmed out to the workers/executors?

Will the `sparkSession.read()...` occur on the driver or does that get submitted to a worker node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re:"how do I tell which code executes on the driver and which code gets farmed out to the workers/executors"

In general any transformations that you do on RDD or Dataframe ( for example map,flatmap,filter,groupBy, reduceByKey etc.) would happen on executor. You usually pass the function or closure while invoking these transformation which would get executed on executor.

When you invoke an action for example "collect" or "take", will bring the data back to driver ( Beware of OutOfMemory errors). Whatever operations you would do on such data collected on Driver, will be executed on Driver.

There is lot of going on when tasks are distributed to executors and things worked out of driver. I would recommend taking the above pointers just as the beginning and go through a book or good tutorial that talks about this.

Comment: Thanks @Amit (+1) - but what about my `sparkSession.read()...` example above? Does the read (that is, reading a file into a `Dataset/DataFrame/RDD`) occur on the driver or an executor? Thanks again!

Comment: read happens on executor to construct the initial state of the RDD. Driver with the help from ApplicationMaster figures the DataNodes on which the data is present that asked to read. Then Driver asks executors to read the data on datanodes and then starts executing the transformations IFF action has been invoke which results in a RDD lineage. Reading Learning Spark would help you with this in detail.